I had a problem installing tensorflow library in Anaconda, which caused a lot of errors, does anyone know how to solve it?
When I installed the tensorflow software library, there was an error:
ERROR:  pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is  the source of the following dependency conflicts.
async-lru 2.0.4 requires typing-extensions>=4.0.0; python_version < "3.11", but you have typing-extensions 3.7.4.3 which is incompatible.
pandas 2.1.3 requires numpy<2,>=1.22.4; python_version < "3.11", but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
scikit-image 0.22.0 requires numpy>=1.22, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
xarray 2023.11.0 requires numpy>=1.22, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
contourpy 1.2.0 requires numpy<2.0,>=1.20, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
mapclassify 2.6.1 requires numpy>=1.23, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
rioxarray 0.15.0 requires numpy>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
scipy 1.11.3 requires numpy<1.28.0,>=1.21.6, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
seaborn 0.13.0 requires numpy! Seaborn 0.13.0 requires numpy! =1.24.0,>=1.20, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.

But after checking the pip list, my numpy version is 1.26.1, so why is there such an error? Does anyone know?



Those aren't errors, they're warnings. The final line says things were successfully installed. Do you have an issue now using tensorflow?

@AKX I imagine that red-colored warnings called ERROR might confuse someone...

@Jeyekomon Sure, but the point stands – does OP have a problem with the library?

TF 2.15 (it seems this version should be installed) need numpy>=1.23.5, so yeah it is a problem if numpy-1.19.5 is "successfully" installed. What about the warnings? Did you try to remove the ~umpy folder manually? This could be the reason that numpy can't get updated to a newer version.

There is still a problem, this is the python code error after I import:
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xf but this version of numpy is 0xd

After that, there was this error:
ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.22.4
your numpy version is 1.19.5.
Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.22.4 to use this pandas version
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
But my numpy version is 1.2.1, so why is there such an error?

@AKX To answer your question: Yes, from the latest OP's comments it does seem that OP has a problem using the library. Warnings often use yellow color, after all.
